# Getting path of file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the C# code below to get the url to an xml file. The current page is News.aspx and the XML file is in the same folder, which is why this works fine.

```
xUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path).Replace("News.aspx", "news.xml");
```

But it feels a little wrong to me, what if News.aspx changed? Is this the right way to do this sort of thing? Or is there a better way to get the URL of a file?

Thanks

Comment: How do you mean a better way? If you know the name of the file, call it directly. There is no way to detect whether it changed on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Server.MapPath` to get the URL of a file.

```
 private string GetPathOfMyXMLFile(string name){
     return Server.MapPath("~/Resources/"+name+".xml");
 }
```

you can then get this in your code

```
 // Bla bla load file
 string path = GetPathOfMyXMLFile("News");
```

You could add *www.donetnukelabs'* suggested answer and pop the name of your xml file into a  settings store (web config perhaps), if it's likely to change.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can resolve this, you can introduce constant in the system, or you can use `appSettings` in web.config to store relative path to the folder for news.xml.

You are right, your current method is not considered good practice.

Comment: Agreed. Use a config setting so that if you want to put the XML file somewhere else or rename it you just have to change a setting in your config file and not recompile your code...